# Bind textfield value to array and put in database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a simple private messing system. When a user sends a message he/she has to fill in three fields: 'to', 'subject' and 'message'. In the 'to' field a user can enter a username to send his/hers message to. Then, using mySql (phpmyadmin), I try to fetch the corresponding user_id from the users table. 
for example, user_id '1' has user_name 'testing'. When a user types in 'testing' in the 'to' field, my code searches in the users table for the user with the user_name 'testing' and takes the corresponding user_id.
After taking the user_id it puts the user_id in the conversations_members table.

My problem is that the code DOES take the correct user_id (I checked this by printing the array), but it doesn't put the correct user_id in the table. It always puts 0.

See code below, here I add the user_id to the array $user_ids

```
   else if(!empty($_POST['to'])){
        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE user_name = :user_name");
        $stmt->bindValue(':user_name', $_POST['to'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();

        $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if ($result) {
            $user_ids['user_id'] = $result['user_id'];
        }
```

See code below, here I try to add the user_id to the table

```
$sql4 = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO conversations_members
                    (conversation_id, user_id, conversation_last_view, conversation_deleted) 
                    VALUES (:conid, :usid, :clv, :condel)");
$sql4->execute(array(
    "conid" => "{$conversation_id}",
    "usid" => "{$user_ids[0]['user_id']}",
    "clv" => "0",
    "condel" => "0"
    ));
```

I really hope anyone can help, I've been struggling for a few hours now :(
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Why do you store the user id in an associative array instead of a simple variable?

Comment: Why are you wrapping variables (such as) `$user_ids[0]['user_id']` in a string?

Comment: In any case... if you assign a value using `$user_ids['user_id']` you won't get it back by doing `$user_ids[0]['user_id']`.

Comment: Do a `print_r($user_ids);` and see what is where in that array. I guess you are addressing it incorrectly

Comment: NOTE: Unnecessary fluff `"conid" => "{$conversation_id}",` write as `"conid" => $conversation_id,`

Comment: NOTE: Unnecessary fluff `"usid" => "{$user_ids[0]['user_id']}",` Write as `"usid" => $user_ids[0]['user_id'],` _Assuming this is a correct array location_

Comment: My guess is it shoud be `"usid" => $user_ids['user_id'],`

Comment: "usid" => $user_ids['user_id'] I tried this and now it's working, thanks!